# How to control the permissions of /html web pages placed in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I put the HTML file in the /html folder in Nginx. Can I control the access path in this case?
Users cannot directly access other HTML pages through the path, they must log in or have permission to access.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/